# Faster to create map of pointers or if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, vector, sfml

I'm creating a game engine using C++ and SFML. I have a class called `character` that will be the base for entities within the game. The `physics` class is also going to handle character movement.

My question is, is it faster to create a vector of pointers to the characters that move in a frame. Then, whenever a function moves a character it places it inside that vector. After the `physics` class is done handling the vector it gets cleared?

Or is it faster to have a `bool` variable that gets set to true whenever a function moves a `character` and then have an if statement inside my `physics` class that tests every `character` for movement?

**EDIT:**
Ok i've gone with a different approach where a function inside the `Physics` class is responsible for dealing with character movement. Immediately upon movement, it tests for collision detection. If collision happens it stops the movement in that direction.

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: If you can detect it, it's faster to just store the pointers to the moved characters instead of (even bit vectors) check for every moved character. Also depends on what comes next.

Comment: Every function having to handle character movement, upon moving a character, would place a pointer to it inside the vector. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Why is it necessary to have a bool necessitating movement for every character?

Comment: The bool tells the physics class that yes this character has been moved. Then the physics class goes through and tests the collision of said movement and if it is not possible then it cancels the movement.

Answer (score 4):

Compared to all the other stuff that is going on in your program (physics, graphics), this will not make a difference. Use the method that makes programming easier because you will not notice a runtime difference at all.

Comment: absolutely. The point is to prevent unnecessary physics engine invokation, because that's where the CPU drain occurs.

Answer (score 2):

If the total number of characters is relatively small, then you won't notice the difference between the approaches.

Else (the number of characters is large), if most of characters move during a frame, then the approach with flag inside a character seems more appropriate, because even with vector of moved characters, you'll traverse all of them and besides that you get additional overhead of maintaining the vector.

Else (the number of characters is large, but only few of them move during a frame), it *may* be better to use vector because it can save you time by not traversing characters which didn't move.

What is a small or large number, depends on your application. You should test under which conditions you get better performance using either of approaches.

Comment: If there is a large number of characters, the physics engine will most likely eat more CPU than whatever method is used to select its invokation anyway. Trying to optimize this selection is a waste of time, that could lead to unnecessarily obfuscated code for neglectible gain, IMHO.

Comment: @kuroineko You can imagine a situation where there is 1M characters and only 10 moving, there may be a visible overhead of traversing them all.

Comment: @kuroi It does indicate a design flaw though. I still don't understand why you need to care about whether a character has moved or not.

Comment: @AntonSavin Well if there is a gazillion objects in the game, you won't have enough memory to handle them all...

Answer (score 1):

This would be the right time to quote Hoare, but I'll abstain. Generally, however, you should profile before you optimize (if, and only if, the time budget is not enough on the minimum spec hardware -- if your game runs at 60fps on the target hardware you will do *nothing whatsoever*).
It is much more likely that the actual physics calculations will be the limiting factor, not doing the "is this unit moving?" check. Also, it is much more likely that submitting draw calls will bite you rather than checking a few hundred or so units.

As an "obvious" thing, it appears to be faster to hold a vector of object pointers and only process the units that are actually moving. However, the "obvious" is not always correct. Iterating linearly over a greater number of elements can very well be faster than jumping around (due to cache). Again, if this part of your game is identified as the bottleneck (very unlikely) then you will have to *measure* which is better.

Comment: This was just something i was more curious about, but thanks for the good response.